# An interpretation of inclusion

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, notation

Let $X$ a vector space on $\mathbb{R}$, $M$ a proper subspace of $X$ and $f\colon M\to \mathbb{R}$ a linear functional. $p$ in this case is a special function, but the definition ot it no nedd now.

I found the following written:

$$P=\left\{g\subseteq X\times\mathbb{R}\;|\; g\;\text{is a map,}\; \text{Dom}(g)\;\text{is a vector subspace of}\; X\;\text{which contains}\;M\;\text{and}\\g\colon \text{Dom}(g)\to\mathbb{R}\;\text{is a linear functional such that}\; g|M=f\;\text{and}\; g(v)\le p(v)\;\text{for all}\; v\in\text{Dom}(g) \right\}$$

> **Question.** What does it mean $$g\subseteq X\times \mathbb{R},$$ is it a legitimate way of writing?

Comment: It means $g$ is a subset of $X \times \mathbb{R}$, to be interpreted as a relation. The first condition "$g$ is a map" means that $g$ is actually the graph of a function, but one whose domain is not all of $X$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan but still there is no relationship, for example with this writing $g$ who is it? Can we say that it is the set of pairs $(x, g (x))$?

Comment: Yes, that's the intended interpretation, except that not all $x$ occur.